# how to make the modes change, that is, looks, plays, listens. I only play for some reason discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const activities_list = ['Watching', 'Playing']; // creates an arraylist containing phrases you want your bot to switch through.

bot.on('ready', () => {
 setInterval(() => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
  bot.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
 }, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, I am assuming that you are trying to change your Client's activity type (`PLAYING`, `STREAMING`, `LISTENING`, `WATCHING`, `CUSTOM_STATUS`) every 10 seconds.

I've written a code explaining how to do that.

---

```js
// We are creating an Array containing the Activity type and message.
const activities_list = [
 {
  type: 'LISTENING',
  message: 'some music.',
 },
 {
  type: 'WATCHING',
  message: 'a movie.',
 },
 {
  type: 'PLAYING',
  message: 'a game.',
 },
];

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`${client.user.tag} is ready.`);

 // Once the Client is ready, we are creating a setInterval that repeats every 10 seconds.
 // The setInterval will run 10 seconds after the Client is ready, not immediately.
 setInterval(() => {
  // Picking a random activity from the activities_list Array.
  const Activity =
   activities_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities_list.length)];

  // client.user.setActivity accepts two parameters, the name and the Object of options. We're going to set the name in the options Object.
  client.user
   .setActivity({
    name: Activity.message,
    type: Activity.type,
   })
   .catch((error) => console.error(`Couldn't set activity status. | ${error}`));
 }, 10 * 1000);

 // 10000ms is the same as 10 * 1000ms, but this way it's more readable.
});
```

Answer (score -5):

For me i use this

```
const activities_list = [
  "Hey", 
  "What's up?",
  "do !help", 
  "contact the developer to report any bug"
  ]; // creates an arraylist containing phrases you want your bot to switch through.

client.on('ready', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
      client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
  }, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @MohammedAlshabeeb Explain why your code solves the problem.

Comment: @MohammedAlshabeeb All you did is add more entries to the array and change the variable names, which honestly has more of a chance of breaking the code rather than fixing it, given we already know that the OP is using another variable name.  Eg, if they were to just drop this in it wouldn't work at all.